# Tomcat hangs at loading XML bean definition

Tags: java, tomcat6, war

I have created War file, of my application, which runs very well in my local tomcat.

Now when I am deploying this WAR file at Server Tomcat, it stops at loading XML bean definition, Tomcat hangs after this, so I have to kill process. How to resolve error.

```
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Oct 19, 2012 1:09:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 812 ms
Oct 19, 2012 1:09:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Oct 19, 2012 1:09:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.32
Oct 19, 2012 1:09:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
Oct 19, 2012 1:09:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor host-manager.xml
Oct 19, 2012 1:09:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
Oct 19, 2012 1:09:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory bms
2012-10-19 13:09:04,654 INFO  [main] [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
2012-10-19 13:09:04,851 INFO  [main] [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Oct 19 13:09:04 UTC 2012]; root of context hierarchy
2012-10-19 13:09:04,981 INFO  [main] [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/application-context.xml]
```

and for this jstack is:

```
2012-10-19 15:06:35
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.2-b06 mixed mode, sharing):

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0881b000 nid=0x55f waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"GC Daemon" daemon prio=10 tid=0xb4568000 nid=0x527 in Object.wait() [0xb43df000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x8436f6d8> (a sun.misc.GC$LatencyLock)
    at sun.misc.GC$Daemon.run(GC.java:100)
    - locked <0x8436f6d8> (a sun.misc.GC$LatencyLock)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Low Memory Detector" daemon prio=10 tid=0xb4500c00 nid=0x525 runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C1 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x08780c00 nid=0x524 runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0877f400 nid=0x523 runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0877bc00 nid=0x522 in Object.wait() [0xb4727000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x842ce0e8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:118)
    - locked <0x842ce0e8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:134)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:159)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x08777000 nid=0x521 in Object.wait() [0xb4777000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x842ce178> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:116)
    - locked <0x842ce178> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"main" prio=10 tid=0x08749000 nid=0x51f runnable [0xb6c4a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOM.processElement(SchemaDOM.java:132)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOM.startElement(SchemaDOM.java:64)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.startElement(SchemaDOMParser.java:251)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2756)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:435)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:491)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.parse(SchemaDOMParser.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHandler.java:1802)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:531)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:552)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1782)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:725)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:377)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2756)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:235)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
    - locked <0x7f220340> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4704)
    - locked <0x844b8038> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    - locked <0x8435bac8> (a java.util.HashMap)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1315)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
    - locked <0x8435ba28> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    - locked <0x8435ba28> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    - locked <0x84348558> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    - locked <0x84348558> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    - locked <0x843609a0> (a [Lorg.apache.catalina.Service;)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x0876cc00 nid=0x520 runnable

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0xb4503400 nid=0x526 waiting on condition

JNI global references: 1296
```

And jstack -F

```
Attaching to process ID 1305, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Client compiler detected.
JVM version is 20.2-b06
Deadlock Detection:

No deadlocks found.

Thread 1375: (state = BLOCKED)


Thread 1319: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.misc.GC$Daemon.run() @bci=51, line=100 (Interpreted frame)

Attaching to process ID 1305, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Client compiler detected.
JVM version is 20.2-b06
Deadlock Detection:

No deadlocks found.

Thread 1375: (state = BLOCKED)


Thread 1319: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.misc.GC$Daemon.run() @bci=51, line=100 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 1315: (state = BLOCKED)


Thread 1314: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(long) @bci=44, line=118 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove() @bci=2, line=134 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run() @bci=3, line=159 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 1313: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=485 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run() @bci=46, line=116 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 1311: (state = BLOCKED)
Error occurred during stack walking:
sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.AssertionFailure: overflow
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.Assert.that(Assert.java:32)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.compiler.OopMapSet.updateRegisterMap(OopMapSet.java:267)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.x86.X86Frame.senderForCompiledFrame(X86Frame.java:354)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.x86.X86Frame.sender(X86Frame.java:283)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.Frame.sender(Frame.java:194)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VFrame.newVFrame(VFrame.java:83)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.JavaThread.getLastJavaVFrameDbg(JavaThread.java:228)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.StackTrace.run(StackTrace.java:76)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.StackTrace.run(StackTrace.java:45)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.run(JStack.java:60)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:221)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.main(JStack.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.runJStackTool(JStack.java:118)
    at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.main(JStack.java:84)

Thread 1315: (state = BLOCKED)


Thread 1314: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(long) @bci=44, line=118 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove() @bci=2, line=134 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run() @bci=3, line=159 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 1313: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=485 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run() @bci=46, line=116 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 1311: (state = BLOCKED)
Error occurred during stack walking:
sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.AssertionFailure: overflow
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.Assert.that(Assert.java:32)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.compiler.OopMapSet.updateRegisterMap(OopMapSet.java:267)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.x86.X86Frame.senderForCompiledFrame(X86Frame.java:354)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.x86.X86Frame.sender(X86Frame.java:283)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.Frame.sender(Frame.java:194)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VFrame.newVFrame(VFrame.java:83)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.JavaThread.getLastJavaVFrameDbg(JavaThread.java:228)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.StackTrace.run(StackTrace.java:76)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.StackTrace.run(StackTrace.java:45)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.run(JStack.java:60)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:221)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.main(JStack.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.runJStackTool(JStack.java:118)
    at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.main(JStack.java:84)
```

I don't know, How to read it. what should I do?

Comment: Can you get a stack-dump to see which bean is causing a problem?  You can use "jstack" to get the dump.

Comment: That looks like it's having some problem reading the schemas.  Something that's bitten me in the past is having the wrong `xsi:schemaLocation` in my bean definition file compared to the version of Spring I was using, so double check that they're right (or that you're using the unversioned schemas such as `http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd`)